# HTTP request in Verilog HDL

Tags: verilog, hdl, intel-fpga

I want to send a HTTP request with Verilog HDL using Altera D2-115 
I'm implementing a security system using smoke detectors and IR breaker circuits, in case of an alarm the system should send a HTTP request to send an email.

Comment: This is not verilog question, dude. All you want is system with ethernet then sent HTTP request. Please discribe more information about it.

Comment: Using ardiuno or another system which interfaces between low level signal and higher level protocols, would greatly simplify this or you are going to have to implement an awful lot in verilog.

Comment: I'm currently using the Altera Board DE2-115 and I am a beginner at this, this is needed for a project in my university, therefore if you could tell me how exactly to use an ethernet to send the HTTP request in ALTERA that would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a FPGA to do a task that is much better suited for a SOC.

That said, you can turn your FPGA into a SOC: instantiate a NIOS-II processor inside your Altera device, connect it to relevant devices, such as RAM, flash-ROM, SD slot for permanent storage, and of course the Ethernet chip, and write a program for the NIOS-II processor that will send the HTTP request via the Ethernet chip. This implies that you will have to include in your program a TCP/IP stack to actually send any information to the Internet, receive any response and managing the handshaking. It has not to be a complete stack, just TCP, IP and possibly ICMP and ARP. UDP is not needed.

If using the DE2-115 board is a personal option and it's not imposed, you may want to look for a microcontroller with a ready made TCP/IP stack and support for Ethernet. A plain Raspberry Pi is much well suited (and way much cheaper), even if you don't actually need a complete Linux system.

Trying to do all the stuff using only Verilog would mean:

- Write a design for a FSM that controls the ethernet chip, possibly
  using SPI for configuration options, and the like.
- That FSM communicates with a large FSM providing the TCP/IP stack.
  It's indeed doable, but a huge project by itself.
- That FSM in turn has to communicate with another FSM which implements the HTTP protocol to send the HTTP request to the remote host.
- And that FSM will be triggered by a simple FSM which is in charge of polling the IR sensors and smoke detectors. This part is the only one I think it is feasible to do as a digital system in Verilog.